# Complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis

Here's a problem I'm struggling with, especially the second question.

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in $\mathbb{D}$, say $f(z) = \sum a_n z^n$. Suppose that $f$ satisfies the following condition :
>
> $$\sum_{n = 2}^{+ \infty} n|a_n| < |a_1| $$
>
> 1. Prove that $f$ takes exactly once the value $a_0$.
> 2. Prove that $f$ is injective.

The first question is simply an application of Rouché's theorem to $f - a_0$ and $a_1 z$. I can't find the answer for the second one.

What I tried and got so far :

- Let $f_n(z) = a_0 + ... + a_n z^n$. They verify the same assumption as $f$, so they take the value $a_0$ only once in $\mathbb{D}$. They converge in $\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$ to $f$, so if we could prove they are injective, Hurwitz theorem would immediately apply. I didn't succeed in proving the injectivity of  $f_n$.
- $f$ and $f_n$ have a nonvanishing derivative. This can be seen simply using the assumption, which yelds $|f'(z) - a_1| < |a_1|$ for every $z \in \mathbb{D}$.

Any help is welcome !
HQ

Comment: A function satisfying the condition of the exercice is never constant, for $|a_1|>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that $f$ is injective, suppose $f(z_1) = f(z_2)$, for distinct $z_1,z_2\in \Bbb D$. Then

$$0 = f(z_2) - f(z_1) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n(z_2^n - z_1^n).$$

Dividing by $z_2 - z_1$, we have

$$0 = a_1 + \sum_{n = 2}^\infty a_n(z_2^{n-1} + z_2^{n-2}z_1 + \cdots + z_2z_1^{n-2} + z_1^{n-1}).$$

That is,

$$-a_1 = \sum_{n = 2}^\infty a_n(z_2^{n-1} + z_2^{n-2}z_1 + \cdots + z_2z_1^{n-1} + z_1^{n-1}).$$

Hence, by the triangle inequality,

$$|a_1| \le \sum_{n = 2}^\infty n|a_n|,$$

contradicting the inequality for $|a_1|$.

Comment: well, this trivializes the two questions without complex analysis. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Apply the Argument Principle to show that the number of times (counting multiplicities) that $f$ takes on a value $w$ is locally constant.

Comment: Ok, here's the thing : since, by the argument principle, the function $w \to n_f (w)$ is locally constant (where $n_f (w)$ is the number of solutions to $f(z) = w$ in $\mathbb{D}$), and because $n_f (a_0) = 1$, then $n_f (w) = 1$ for every $w \in \mathrm{im} f$ (which is open).

Comment: Sorry to unearth the topic, but in fact things are not clear to me with your hint. When I tried to write it precisely, I couldn't get it. Could you write everything in detail ?

Comment: In fact, I feel like your argument is wrong on other situations. Here's an example of what bothers me (not linked with the problem). Let me take the function $f : z \to z^2$ defined on $U =D(1, \frac{1}{2})$. It is clear that $1$ is a simple root in $U$ for the equation $z^2 = 1$, so $n(1) = 1$. According to your argument, the function $w \to n(w)$ is locally constant on $D$, therefore it must be constant and equal to $n(1) = 1$, which is wrong, because $n(0) = 2$. So, there's something wrong on my interpretation of your hint and it made me do nightmares this night.

Comment: Well, no, on the disk you gave, $n(0)=0$. The point is that as you perturb the value $w$, the number of solutions $$n(w)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)-w}dz$$ is only a continuous (hence locally constant) function of $w$ so long as you keep the integrand continuous. In particular, $w$ can never be a root of $f$ on $\gamma$. So, in your example, if you take a path joining $w=1$ to $w=0$, it will cross $w=1/4$, which is a value of $f(z)=z^2$ on $\partial U$. P.S. Sorry about the nightmares.

Comment: whops, I meant the disk $D(\frac{1}{2},1)$.

Comment: My explanation will apply, regardless. In order for $n(w)$ to change as you move $w$, the values of $f$ along $\gamma$ will cross the path along which you move $w$. Try it!

Comment: I'm ok with what you said concerning the general fact that $w \to n(w)$ is locally constant on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathrm{im}( f\circ \gamma )$. The rest is currently processing in my brain, I'll keep in touch.

Comment: A tout à l'heure :)

Comment: Back to the problem. Take $w$ in the image of $f$. How do we know that $w$ is in the connected component of $a_0$ ? e.g. how do we know that the path from $w$ to $a_0$ won't cross the image of $f \circ \gamma $ ?

Comment: In your original Rouché argument, I presume you took for $\gamma$ a circle of radius $r<1$ (with $r$ as close to $1$ as we want). Since the image of $f$ is connected (and open), any path from $a_0$ to $w$ stays inside the image, and $\partial\Bbb D_r$ must map to the boundary (either use open mapping or apply our argument on $\Bbb D_{r'}$, with $r<r'<1$).